# PHP Curl accessing file always show 403 error

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

I am trying to access a JSON file through Curl but it always shows a 403 forbidden error.

I am using Cloudflare on my site.

Here is the code, only else block is running.

I can access this JSON through `browser and FTP` there is no error but through `Curl and wget` it shows `403`.

```
$url = "https://example.com/pub/media/sample.json";
            
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: curl/7.39.0');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

if ($code == 200) {
    $status = true;
} else {
    $status = false;
}
curl_close($ch);
        
if ($status){
    echo 'sucess';
}
else{
    echo  $code.' My File Error '. $url;
    
}
```

Comment: `echo  $code.' My File Error '. $url]);` doesn't show an error?

Comment: Curl Errors are found like [this in the manual](https://www.php.net/curl_%20error)

Comment: Can you access that URL using a browser

Comment: @brombeer I have fixed this line of code it was typo, basically this shows a 403 then static string and file path

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i can access the file using browser

Comment: Just the browser? No use of the website or login done?

Comment: Also you say you can access using FTP, but then say when you use `FGET` it fails, but `fget is FTP i believe? I am a little confused

Comment: It is not ```fget``` but ```wget```

Comment: Ok, that is also FTP syntax

Comment: from ```CLI/SSH``` ```curl https://example.com/pub/media/sample.json --verbose``` shows Sorry, you have been blocked by cloudflare.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my issue.

I was using `Curl` on my server to access files but it was not allowing `Curl` or `WGET` to access any file and Cloudflare was blocking all requests.

I went to Cloudflare and whitelisted the my server own IP in

```
Security -> Web Application Firewall (WAF)
```